# Android Emulator can't connect to Mongo Atlas

Tags: android, mongodb, flutter, android-emulator

I'm a newbie trying to build my first Flutter app whilst using MongoDB Atlas as a database, however when I try the following code:

```
  final db = await Db.create('mongodb+srv://admin:***@cluster0.z286eob.mongodb.net/****?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
  print("AHH");
  await db.open();
```

The `AHH` never gets printed, ever. The `***` in the URL represents my user password and database name, and they're correct because
**It works when I try it on a real device, but not on the Android emulator** with Android Studio.
Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to be some sort of bug with the emulator. When I tried it in a new one, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Internet permission in AndroidManifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The manifest file will be here : `projectdirectory/android/app/src/main`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/duO94.png]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it still didn't work :c

Comment: Do you have wifi turn on emulator and can you share emulator android os version and real device os version